# Can anyone explain how 'stimulus / response' appears in Chinese or Japanese Buddhism?

Tags: chinese-buddhism, japan

- Can anyone explain how 'stimulus / response' appears in [*Chinese*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Buddhism) or [*Japanese Buddhism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhism_in_Japan)?
- What does it mean?

I can recall barely nothing about it, but I do know that it features in Zhiyi's work, *[Chin Fa-hua-hsüan-i](https://www.nichirenlibrary.org/en/dic/Content/P/109)* at least. I'm especially interested in how the terms, which I believe are paired, may have a universal meaning.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extremely broad question, I will limit my response to Ch'an/Zen Buddhism.

Starting in the earliest schools of Ch'an in Sung China, we find the practice of a stimulus/response ritual the Japanese call *sassho*. It usually (but not necessarily) takes the form of a question-answer dialog between master and student and is used to both invoke and verify insight/realization. Some of these dialogs have become (in)famous and were compiled into [Kung'An/Koan collections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%8Dan#Classical_k%C5%8Dan_collections) still used today.

The basic philosophy behind sassho is to verify whether the answer to a teacher's question is free-flowing or (pre)conceived. In the latter case, the answer would be rejected and the student would be requested to meditate further on the question.